# Accessing array elements (get_pages)

Tags: array

I'm trying to access the page ID of the child so that I can recursively call the get_children function on that child (to get grandchildren).

```
    if ($CurrentPage) {
        $args = array(
            'child_of' => $CurrentPage
            );
        $children = get_pages( $args );

        foreach ($children as $key => $value) {
                echo $key.'=>'.$value.'<br />';
        } // End foreach.
    } // End IF.
```

I actually get an error: **Catchable fatal error:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return set of $children is an associative array. So you can get the IDs with:

```
$children = get_children( $args );

foreach ($children as $k => $v) {
    echo $k;
    // do stuff with $v
}
```

Comment: If I run foreach $children as $child => $element, and I want to call the ID, I run $child['ID'] = $ID, echo $ID. I'm lost.

Comment: In my example, $k is the ID.

Comment: Hm, if each $child holds an array of attributes: say ID = page ID, parent = parent ID, I don't believe your syntax makes sense. I'm not asking for the element ID. I'm asking for the specified page ID in the array of get_children (actually, I just switched to get_pages).

Comment: $children is an associative array with the page ID as the key, and the page properties the value. Do a print_r($children) for more information. Trust me - $k is the Wordpress Page ID.

Comment: My output is like this: [ID] => 124
            [post_author] => 1, etc... So if i want to output 124, I need to output $v where $k = ['ID']. Right?

Comment: Correction: the array is actually composed of objects. That's why I get that error.